# How to change product name in frontend

Tags: magento2

I want to change a CSS style and position for product name, price, brand name and reviews on products card.

Here is current CSS style:

[image]

Here is the look that I would like to get

[image]

Anyone help me which files I should edit?

@ update

How to change style also for old price in `list.phtml`?

I centered all text but impossible center old price.

[image]

In list.phtml I have only:

```
<div align="center"><span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Cena det.') ?></span></div><div align="center"><?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?></div>
```

I cannot find `oldprice`

Comment: I didn't undestand what you want to do here ? you want to change a product name or product name style or, but here you have two different products, we can't undedertand your need, share rather the same product before and after please.

Comment: @Prince, I described you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the `list.phtml` (If you haven't already in your current theme) from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Then reorder the items as your need, for css you can customise them in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/yourcss.css`

Comment: I  updated my topic

Comment: Did you solve what you wanted to do?

Comment: yes but still I cannot center "Old Price".

Comment: Try: `.old-price {display: block; text-align: center;}`